# Create View view_Name in sqlite database using c#.net

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using sqlite database with c#.
I created one database having one table with 26 columns. I want to create view so that while reading it will read from view instead of query.

I want to create view just because while reading from database using SQLiteAdapter.Fill()
it takes 5-6 sec to gel all entries with all fields.

So if there is any other way to reduce time or else How to create view in c# with SQLite.

Comment: Views do not increase speed.

Comment: How many records are we talking about?

Comment: If Views not increase the speed then how can i increase speed?
and nearby 80K and above records in that table.

Comment: If you create view with less column rather than cols table, you can speed up, but this time depending on where are db. Shared folder or same machine ? If db are on network share you can gain some time (depending on amount of data transferred). If you filter your data consider using index.